# How to display list of accounts and prompt the customer to choose which specific account?

Tags: java

I have been stuck on this for more than 3 days now.

In my main class, `ATM`, in method `verifyCustomer()`. When signing in, I'm trying to find a way to ask for a customer ID first. Once verified, then the customers accounts will be listed. After that, the customer will then be prompted to choose which account they want to access, and from there they will be prompted to enter the account number and then the password.

I also have a Gold Account class in which only customers above a certain age "65" are allowed the option to open up. I am having trouble figuring out the logic on how to access that in the `initialize()` method as well.

I have 3 subclasses to the `Account` superclass which I didn't include due to there already being too much code.

Any tips?

**ATM.java**

```java
public class ATM {
    private InputReader reader;
    private String accountNumber;
    private String passcode;
    private boolean customerVerified;
    private String customerID;

    private Bank theBank;
    private Customer currentCustomer;

    public ATM() {
        super();
        initialize();
        run();
    }
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ATM();
    }

    public void run() {
        reader = new InputReader();
        boolean exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to Bank");
            System.out.println("Choose one of the following options");
            System.out.println("1 - Sign In");
            System.out.println("2 - Deposit");
            System.out.println("3 - Withdraw");
            System.out.println("4 - Display Account Info");
            System.out.println("5 - Exit");
            System.out.println(">");
            int choice = reader.getIntInput();

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    verifyCustomer();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    transactDeposit();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    transactWithdraw();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    displayAccountInformation();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Thank you for banking at Bank");
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
  
    public void initialize() {
        Customer tom = new Customer("Tom", "Smith", "123",70,"A001");
        Customer jane = new Customer("Jane", "Smith", "789",18,"A002");
        Customer bob = new Customer("Bob", "Smith", "456",32,"A003");

        Account tomChequing = new ChequingAccount("CH-123", 0.0,2);
        Account tomSavings = new SavingsAccount("SA-123", 50.0);
        Account tomGold = new GoldAccount("GL-123",50.0,2.0);

        Account janeChequing = new ChequingAccount("CH-789",0.0,2);
        Account janeSavings = new SavingsAccount("SA-789", 0.0);

        Account bobChequings = new ChequingAccount("CH-456",0.0,5);
        Account bobSavings = new SavingsAccount("SA-456", 100.0);

        tom.addAccount(tomChequing);
        tom.addAccount(tomSavings);
        tom.addAccount(tomGold);

        jane.addAccount(janeChequing);
        jane.addAccount(janeSavings);

        bob.addAccount(bobChequings);
        bob.addAccount(bobSavings);

        theBank = new Bank();
        theBank.addCustomer(tom);
        theBank.addCustomer(jane);
        theBank.addCustomer(bob);

        if(currentCustomer.getAge() >= 65) {
            currentCustomer.
        }
    }
    
    public void transactDeposit() {
        if (customerVerified) {
            System.out.println("Enter the amount to deposit: ");
            currentCustomer.getAccountList().addToBalance(reader.getDoubleInput());
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: You must LOGIN before you can perform a transaction.");
            verifyCustomer();
        }
    }

    public void transactWithdraw() {
        if (customerVerified) {
            System.out.println("Enter the amount to withdraw: ");
            currentCustomer.getAccount().subtractFromBalance(reader.getDoubleInput());
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: You must LOGIN before you can perform a transaction.");
            verifyCustomer();
        }
    }

    public void displayAccountInformation() {
        if (customerVerified) {
            System.out.println("Here is your information.");
            System.out.println(currentCustomer.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: You must LOGIN before you can perform a trasnsaction.");
            verifyCustomer();
        }
    }

    public void verifyCustomer() {
        System.out.println("Enter your Customer ID");
        customerID = reader.getStringInput();

        System.out.println("Which account do you want to access?");

        System.out.println("Enter Account Number: ");
        accountNumber = reader.getStringInput();
        System.out.println("Enter your passcode");
        passcode = reader.getStringInput();

        currentCustomer = Bank.theBank.get(accountNumber);
        if (currentCustomer != null) {
            if (passcode.equals(currentCustomer.getPasscode()) && customerID.equals(currentCustomer.getCustomerID())) {
                customerVerified = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Either account number, customer id, or passcode is not correct.");
                run();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Either account number, customer id, or passcode is not correct.");
            run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String passcode;
    private int age;
    private String customerID;
    private ArrayList<Account> accounts;

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String passcode, int age, String customerID) {
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
        setPasscode(passcode);
        setAge(age);
        setCustomerID(customerID);
        accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addAccount(Account account) {
        accounts.add(account);
    }

    public ArrayList<Account> getAccountList() {
        return accounts;
    }

    public void setAccountList(ArrayList<Account> account) {
        this.accounts = account;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        if (firstName != null && !firstName.trim().isEmpty()) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        if (lastName != null && !lastName.trim().isEmpty()) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }

    public String getPasscode() {
        return passcode;
    }

    public void setPasscode(String passcode) {
        if (passcode != null && !passcode.trim().isEmpty()) {
            this.passcode = passcode;
        }
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getCustomerID() {
        return customerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(String customerID){
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }
}
```

**Account.java**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Account {
    private String accountNumber;
    private double balance;
    private boolean active;
    protected ArrayList<String> transactionInfo;

    public Account() {
        super();
    }

    public Account(String accountNumber, double balance) {
        super();
        if(accountNumber != null) {
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        }

        setBalance(balance);
        active = true;

        transactionInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        if(balance >= 0){
            this.balance = balance;
        }
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public void addToBalance(double amount) {
        if (amount > 0) {
            balance += amount;
        }
    }

    public void subtractFromBalance(double amount) {
        if (amount > 0) {
            balance -= amount;
        }
    }

    public void addTransactionInfo(String info) {
        if(info != null) {
            transactionInfo.add(info);
        }
    }

    public void displayAccountRecords() {
        if(transactionInfo != null) {
            for(String info: transactionInfo) {
                System.out.println(info);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Bank.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Bank {
    public static HashMap<String, Customer> theBank;

    public Bank() {
        super();
        theBank = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer newCustomer) {
        if (newCustomer != null) {
            theBank.put(newCustomer.getCustomerID(), newCustomer);
        }
    }

    // use the customerID to access their collection of accounts

    public void closeAccount(String customerID, String accountNumber) {
        Customer c = theBank.get(customerID);
        if(c != null) {
            for(Account a: c.getAccountList()) {
                if(accountNumber.equals(a.getAccountNumber())) {
                    theBank.remove(accountNumber);

                }
            }
        //if (theBank.containsKey(customerID)) {
        //theBank.get(customerID).getAccountList().remove(accountNumber);
        }
    }

    public static void displayCustomerInformation(Customer customer){
        if(customer != null){
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
    }

    public static void displayAllCustomers(){
        for(Customer customer : theBank.values()){
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `HashMap` in class `Bank` and the map key is customer ID. Just add a `getCustomer(String)` method in class `Bank`.

```java
public Customer getCustomer(String id) {
    return theBank.get(id);
}
```